# Cargar formulario que incluya archivos pdf en MVC, C#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, razor

[image: Imagen del formulario]Estoy haciendo un formulario para el registro de oficios a los cuales necesito adjuntarle archivos pdf a cada uno, ya he podido realizar el guardado de los demas campos, el problema radica cuando quiero enviar el archivo pdf junto con todo lo demás campos y guardarlo en mi base de datos, no encuentro la formas de hacerlo.(he visto ejemplos de solo subir el PDF pero no he podido realizar el cargado de todo, al mismo tiempo).
lo que utilizo es: SQLServer, C#.net, visual studio, Razor.

Saludos.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Mírate esto:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/3463a5ba-20b5-4acb-81b2-95a5e191f040/cargar-documento-pdf-c?forum=vcses     Aquí se sube un PDF a  un SQL Server. Con la poca información que ofreces, creo que esto es lo que solicitas.